# Re-rendering component when any object value changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an user object with all user data inside.

```
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)

    const unsub = onSnapshot(docRef, (doc) => {
      setUserData(doc.data())
  });
```

This onSnapshot func triggers when a value changes in the database so the userData variable is always set to the new value.

I then pass this as a prop in my Navbar component so I can display the data.

```
<Navbar key={userData} user={userData}/>
```

The problem is that the Navbar component won't re-render with the new data.
How can I re-render the Navbar component when userData changes?

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you're trying to describe.  `<Navbar>` will re-render if its props change.  So as long as you're updating (not mutating) the state of `userData` then the component will re-render.  For the key, is this the `key` prop used when mapping over an array of data?  Something else?  Ideally you'd use some property on the array over which you're mapping which uniquely identifies that record, though in many cases the array index itself suits the task.  Can you clarify the problem you're observing, perhaps with a runnable [mcve]?

Comment: Why do you need a key?  Do you have a _list_ of `Navbar` components?

Comment: @David Well yes, that's also what I thought. But it does not re-render when userData changes. That's why I thought I need to a use key.

Comment: @Jaydendev: *"But it does not re-render when userData changes."* - Nowhere in the code shown does `userData` ever change.  *"That's why I thought I need to a use key."* - What specific debugging observations led you to this conclusion?  Currently you're asking us why your solution to some other problem doesn't work, but we know nothing about that other problem.

Comment: I extended the question with more info.

Comment: How is `onSnapshot` invoked?  What is the `doc` argument to the callback?  What does `doc.data()` return?  If throughout this sequence of events everything is using the same reference to `userData` then the operation isn't technically updating state.  This is why a [mcve] is often important.  Just describing what you think is happening in the code may not be providing necessary information about the problem.

Comment: doc.data() returns the user object

Comment: @Jaydendev: And is "the user object" the same object instance as `userData`?  Mutating an object and assigning that same object back to state is incorrect usage of React and doesn't constitute a state update.  You need to update state to a new object instance in order to trigger a re-render.  (It looks like the answer below has already indicated this...)

Answer (score 2):

> This object changes whenever anything changes in the database.

Assuming you mean that a **new** object is used, like this:

```
const newObjectFromDataBase = await getObjectFromDataBase();
setUserData(newObjectFromDataBase);
```

...then that's fine. You don't need a key unless this is in a list, and if it is in a list you want a key that *won't* change (like the user's ID if there is one).

Example:

```js
"use strict";
const { useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

const getObjectFromDataBase = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({ id: 42, name: "Joe Bloggs", lastUpdated: Date.now() });
        }, 100);
    });
};

const NavBar = ({ user }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {user.name}, last updated {new Date(user.lastUpdated).toISOString()}
        </div>
    );
};

const Example = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null); //will become an object when filled with user data
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const updateUser = useCallback(() => {
        getObjectFromDataBase().then(setUserData).catch(setError);
    });
    useEffect(updateUser, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {error && <div>Error: {error.message || String(error)}</div>}
            {userData && <NavBar user={userData} />}
            <div>
                <input type="button" value="Update User" onClick={updateUser} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

What you don't want to do is **modify** the `userData` object, like this:

```
// DON'T DO THIS
userData.name = "Some new name";
```

...since that won't cause a re-render. More in [the React documentation](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state).

Comment: I get back a new object when data changes, and state would be set to that object. But the component won't re-render. I don't have a list, but since it didn't re-render I thought I need to use a key.

Comment: @Jaydendev could you share your code you use to update the user using `setUserData()`, generally component should rerender if you update the parent component state causing the parent component to rerender.

Comment: I extended the question with more info.

Comment: @Jaydendev - What you've shown will cause re-rendering, no key required. At least, that's true assuming `doc.data()` returns a different object each time it's called (or at least a different object when the snapshot event occurs). So that would be one of the first things to check: Does it? If not, change the setter to `setUserData({...doc.data()});` to explicitly create one.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I found what the issue was this morning and fixed it.